# OpenALPR image recognition fails with image from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I've managed to get the OpenALPR library working within my app when passing a static image as per the example, but when using an image from the camera recognition is unsuccessful every time - is there something different about the image thats returned from a AVCaptureSession()?

Here's the code I'm using to get the image:

```
NSData* imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:sampleBuffer];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cv::Mat cvImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];
[self.plateScanner scanImage:cvImage onSuccess:^(NSArray * results) {
// Never suceeds
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code.

```
self.plateScanner = [[PlateScanner alloc] init];
self.plates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

cv::Mat image1  = [self cvMatFromUIImage:chosenImage];

[self.plateScanner
 scanImage:image1
 onSuccess:^(NSArray * results) {
     [self.plates addObjectsFromArray:results];
 }
 onFailure:^(NSError * error) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         [self showErrorDialogWithTitle:@"Error with scan."
                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to process license plate image: %@", [error localizedDescription]]];
     });
 }];
```

This is working fine for me.
Did you alloc init "self.plateScanner" ?

Comment: Maybe you can help to do the same thing but with image stream? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997900/how-to-convert-cmsamplebuffer-to-stdvectorchar